# Aggregating Columns with conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following dataset (there are many rows):

```
        NUM     POS   SKU   STORE   FOR        DATE     PRICE   QTD DEV
1   93591601    10  37350   HC01    8740    2017-01-02  76.00   1.0 0.0
2   93591701    20  37350   HC01    8740    2017-01-02  83.49   1.0 0.0

3   93592369    20  37350   HC01    8740    2017-01-04  92.90   1.0 0.0
4   93592440    20  37350   HC01    8740    2017-01-04  88.85   1.0 0.0
5   93592697    20  37350   HC01    8740    2017-01-04  78.38   1.0 0.0
```

What I am trying to do is to group by ('SKU', 'STORE', 'DATA'), and Aggragate the rows

- some of them using `sum`,
- others calculating the `mean`
- others *keeping the last row of the group*.

In python I can do this using this function:

```
df = df.groupby(['SKU', 'STORE', 'DATA']).agg({'PRICE': np.mean,
                                             'QTD':np.sum,
                                             'DEV':'last',
                                             'FOR':'last',
                                             }).reset_index()



        NUM     POS   SKU   STORE   FOR        DATE     PRICE   QTD DEV
1   93591601    10  37350   HC01    8740    2017-01-02  79.74   2.0 0.0
2   93591701    20  37350   HC01    8740    2017-01-04  86.71   3.0 0.0
```

How can I do this using sql ?

Supposing that the table name is DT:

```
SELECT 
MEAN(PRICE),
SUM(QTD)
FROM DT
GROUP BY 'SKU', 'STORE', 'DATA'
```

How do I get the last row value from each group ?

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Comment: Do you mean you want to use the last row? or the maximum from that column? If the former, lookup rank, row_number, or other similar sequential windowed functions so that the last can be later selected via a WHERE clause or similar.

Comment: you are grouping by three constant values (strings), not by column names.

Comment: I am using SQL Server

Comment: Last row, I mean, getting the last row value of each group

Answer (score -1):

```
    SELECT
SKU, STORE, DATA,
    AVG(PRICE),
    SUM(QTD),
    MAX(FOR),
    MAX(DEV),
    FROM DT
    GROUP BY SKU, STORE, DATA
```

EDIT. As has been suggested I replaced MEAN with AVG (Works for all the database providers I know)
If you want to get values of FOR and DEV corresponding to highest date or something you can replicate this solution:
[Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

Comment: How did u assumed using `Mean` without knowing DBMS and in which DBMS this query will work ?

Comment: Author used it in his example :)

Comment: you still didn't answered my question, which DBMS `mean` will work ?

Comment: oah, you are right. I assumed query from post worked. Sorry

Comment: And does this query now ensures OP gets last row ?

Comment: last rows of FOR and DEV. MAX and MIN are both working for numerical and alphabetical order.

Comment: You are trying to make an effort, appreciate it. Atleast try and get some sample data into your query, your query has syntax errros and  all over the place, try and execute with sample data into temp table before posting

Comment: It actually worked in my database, with comperable data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194503/discussion-between-arkadiusz-raszeja-and-ven).